# Nested Transformation

Tags: xslt

I try to perform a Transformation to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A_Example>
    <A_ExampleType>
    
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
    </A_ExampleType>
    
    <A_ExampleType>
    
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
    </A_ExampleType>
    
    <A_ExampleType>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
      <to_ExampleChild>
        <A_ExampleChildType>
          
         <RandomChildData1></RandomChildData1>
         <RandomChildData2></RandomChildData2>
         <RandomChildData3></RandomChildData3>
         <RandomChildData4></RandomChildData4>
         <RandomChildData5></RandomChildData5>
         <RandomChildData6></RandomChildData6>
          <to_ExampleArea>
            <A_ExampleAreaType>
            
            <RandomAreaData1></RandomAreaData1>
            <RandomAreaData2></RandomAreaData2>
            <RandomAreaData3></RandomAreaData3>
            <RandomAreaData4></RandomAreaData4>
            <RandomAreaData5></RandomAreaData5>
            <RandomAreaData6></RandomAreaData6>
      
            </A_ExampleAreaType>
          </to_ExampleArea>
          
           <RandomData1></RandomData1>
           <RandomData2></RandomData2>
           <RandomData3></RandomData3>
           <RandomData4></RandomData4>
           <RandomData5></RandomData5>
           <RandomData6></RandomData6>
           
        </A_ExampleChildType>
      </to_ExampleChild>
      
      
         <RandomData1></RandomData1>
         <RandomData2></RandomData2>
         <RandomData3></RandomData3>
         <RandomData4></RandomData4>
         <RandomData5></RandomData5>
         <RandomData6></RandomData6>
   
    </A_ExampleType>
    
        <A_ExampleType>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
      <to_ExampleChild>
        <A_ExampleChildType>
          
         <RandomChildData1></RandomChildData1>
         <RandomChildData2></RandomChildData2>
         <RandomChildData3></RandomChildData3>
         <RandomChildData4></RandomChildData4>
         <RandomChildData5></RandomChildData5>
         <RandomChildData6></RandomChildData6>
          <to_ExampleArea>
            <A_ExampleAreaType>
            
            <RandomAreaData1></RandomAreaData1>
            <RandomAreaData2></RandomAreaData2>
            <RandomAreaData3></RandomAreaData3>
            <RandomAreaData4></RandomAreaData4>
            <RandomAreaData5></RandomAreaData5>
            <RandomAreaData6></RandomAreaData6>
      
            </A_ExampleAreaType>
          </to_ExampleArea>
          
           <RandomData1></RandomData1>
           <RandomData2></RandomData2>
           <RandomData3></RandomData3>
           <RandomData4></RandomData4>
           <RandomData5></RandomData5>
           <RandomData6></RandomData6>
           
        </A_ExampleChildType>
        </to_ExampleChild>
      
      
         <RandomData1></RandomData1>
         <RandomData2></RandomData2>
         <RandomData3></RandomData3>
         <RandomData4></RandomData4>
         <RandomData5></RandomData5>
         <RandomData6></RandomData6>
   
    </A_ExampleType>
</A_Example>
```

I want to achieve the following output:

```
<A_Example>
    <A_ExampleType>
    
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
    </A_ExampleType>
    
    <A_ExampleType>
    
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
    </A_ExampleType>
    
    <A_ExampleType>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
    
    
          
    <RandomChildData1></RandomChildData1
    <RandomChildData2></RandomChildData2>
    <RandomChildData3></RandomChildData3>
    <RandomChildData4></RandomChildData4>
    <RandomChildData5></RandomChildData5>
    <RandomChildData6></RandomChildData6>
            
    <RandomAreaData1></RandomAreaData1>
    <RandomAreaData2></RandomAreaData2>
    <RandomAreaData3></RandomAreaData3>
    <RandomAreaData4></RandomAreaData4>
    <RandomAreaData5></RandomAreaData5>
    <RandomAreaData6></RandomAreaData6>
          
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
   
    </A_ExampleType>
    
     <A_ExampleType>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
          
    <RandomChildData1></RandomChildData1>
    <RandomChildData2></RandomChildData2>
    <RandomChildData3></RandomChildData3>
    <RandomChildData4></RandomChildData4>
    <RandomChildData5></RandomChildData5>
    <RandomChildData6></RandomChildData6>
            
    <RandomAreaData1></RandomAreaData1>
    <RandomAreaData2></RandomAreaData2>
    <RandomAreaData3></RandomAreaData3>
    <RandomAreaData4></RandomAreaData4>
    <RandomAreaData5></RandomAreaData5>
    <RandomAreaData6></RandomAreaData6>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
      
    <RandomData1></RandomData1>
    <RandomData2></RandomData2>
    <RandomData3></RandomData3>
    <RandomData4></RandomData4>
    <RandomData5></RandomData5>
    <RandomData6></RandomData6>
   
    </A_ExampleType>
</A_Example>
```

In short I want a flat structure without the nested nodes. I tried to approach with the following XSLT but didn't get very far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/A_Example">
    <test>
    <xsl:for-each select="//A_ExampleType">
    <hallo>
        <xsl:value-of select="."></xsl:value-of>
    </hallo>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </test>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I run my code, I get the whole data also the Data from all nodes but without the declaration. With this I mean I get something like this.

XML before run XSLT code:

```
<RandomData1>Test12345</RandomData1>
```

XML after I run the XSLT code I only get:

```
         Test12345
```

Why is this happening and how can I get the declaration back?

Comment: If you only want to copy descendants of `A_ExampleType` that don't have any child elements to the output then you can either select them with e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(*)]"/>` or you need to make sure you have a default processing set up to skip anything but these elements with e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-skip"/>` and then you set up a template matching `A_Example | A_ExampleType | A_ExampleType//*[not(*)]` that does an identity transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want the 'leaf' nodes (nodes without child nodes) starting from your 2nd nesting level (*A_ExampleType*), I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/A_Example">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="A_ExampleType">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="descendant::*[not(child::*)]"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: sry for not replieying. Your answer solves my prblem. But i dont understand what produce the error in my transformation. Could you pleas explain this to me?

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="somexpath"/>` gets you the content of (nested) _text nodes_ specified by your xpath: In your example, "Test12345" is a text node. Whereas _<xsl:copy...>_ or _<xsl:copy-of...>_ get you the complete XML nodes as specified by the xpath.